# Powershell: Save a workbook with SaveAs and a variable in file name

Tags: arrays, excel, powershell

I have this strange problem with a script, I hope someone can help.

Thce script take data from a csv, open a workbook and put the data in place with a replacement, it continue do this till there's data to take, the problem is that I'd like to save the file with one of the variables I took from the .csv.
The script work itself but when the file is saved the variable was not taken and it continue going to create the same filename requesting me if I want to replace it.

here the script

```
Import-Csv C:\AZRconf\Batch.csv | ForEach-Object {
$site = $_.site
$uds = $_.uds
$jms = $_.jms

$objExcel = New-Object -com Excel.Application
$wb = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\AZRconf\Automation_Configuration_2.23.2.0_NS\ConfigurationAutomationNS.csv")
$sheet = $wb.ActiveSheet
[void]$sheet.Cells.Replace("XXX", "$site", [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt]::xlPart)
[void]$sheet.Cells.Replace("YYY.ZZZ.YYY.ZZZ", "$uds", [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt]::xlPart)
[void]$sheet.Cells.Replace("@@@@@@@@@@@@", "$jms", [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt]::xlPart)
$path = "C:\AZRconf\TempNS\ConfigurationAutomation_NS_($site).csv"
$wb.SaveAs($Path)
$objExcel.Quit()
}
```

and the script try to save the file as C:\AZRconf\TempNS\ConfigurationAutomation_NS_().csv, asking for any loop if I want to replace it with a different file with the same filename.
so, it don't take the $site variable.

Any hint?

Comment: This is just a matter of trouble shooting: just add some lines to the script like: `Write-Host $_.site`, `Write-Host $_.site` and `Write-Host $Path`.

Comment: Check what character is used in the input csv file. Without specifying that, the Import-Csv cmdlet defaults to a comma. Looks like your file has something different like a semi-colon `;` or something.